# How to update RAM amount, after changing in BIOS?

Tags: uefi, ram

In my Lenovo x1 carbon 2015 UEFI/BIOS I can choose between 256 and 512 MB GPU ram. If I choose 512, it will take 256 MB from the normal ram, giving me only 7,7 GB left.

After changing this back to 256 MB, it still reports as having only 7.7 GB.

I suspect I had 512 chosen when I installed, but now I need ram, so I want the last 256 MB back :)

How to solve this?

It's a Ubuntu 16.04 fresh install with a UEFI partition.

```
➜  ~ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7,7G        2,3G        4,0G        382M        1,3G        4,8G
```

Comment: What does `free --si -h` show?  The `--si` means to use the power of 1000 instead of 1024 which can show a better reading of your RAM.

Comment: Then it shows 8.1GB. But it still shows the same amount, if I choose 256 or 512mb ram to the GPU.

Comment: Try it without the `-h`.  It might be rounding up to show the totals.

Comment: You should've titled this question with "VRAM" or "GPU RAM". Your question sounds confusing otherwise.